# DEMA & TEMA Ta-lib Java Implementation

Tags: java, ta-lib

I am currently working with [Ta-lib Java](http://sourceforge.net/p/ta-lib/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/ta-lib/java/) implementations. I can run properly MA & SUM. But having problem while try to run DEMA, TEMA. The output is all zeros.
I am calling the DEMA & TEMA method of Ta-lib as follows

```
import com.tictactec.ta.lib.Core;
import com.tictactec.ta.lib.MInteger;


public class TALibJava {
    double[] array = {207.650, 205.160, 210.870, 209.350, 207.250, 209.960, 207.650, 205.160, 188.170, 186.020};
    double[] output = new double[array.length];
    int period = 5;
    Core core = new Core();
    int lookback = 0;
    MInteger begin = new MInteger();
    MInteger length = new MInteger();

    public void callDEMA() {
        lookback = core.demaLookback(period);
        core.dema(0, array.length - 1, array, 0, begin, length, output);
        System.out.println("DEMA Output: ");
        print();
    }

    public void callTEMA() {
        lookback = core.temaLookback(period);
        core.tema(0, array.length - 1, array, 0, begin, length, output);
        System.out.println("TEMA Output: ");
        print();
    }

    public void print() {
        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
            System.out.print(output[i] + "\t ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        TALibJava obj = new TALibJava();
        obj.callDEMA();
        obj.callTEMA();
    }

}
```

Perhaps the input parameters are not properly set. Please suggest me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You should provide a complete, runnable minimal sample code showing the issue

Comment: Thanks RC for your comment. Please let me update the full runnable code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [source code of `dema()`](http://sourceforge.net/p/ta-lib/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/ta-lib/java/src/com/tictactec/ta/lib/Core.java#l12436), `optInTimePeriod` cannot be `0`:

```
else if( ((int)optInTimePeriod < 2) || ((int)optInTimePeriod > 100000) )
     return RetCode.BadParam ;
```

That's why your current code returns "BadParam" and not "Success" when you call `dema()`.

(Same thing goes for `tema()`)

Comment: I have changed the calling of dema as below. Still I'm getting all zeros as output.

    core.dema(0, array.length - 1, array, lookback + 1, begin, length, output);

Comment: What is this optInTimePeriod? could you please explain it?